# How to get a repetitive pattern

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a text Box where the user enters the integer. and then I want to list the number till the integer entered by user. The list will have first to be RED, second to be YELLOW and third to be GREEN. This pattern will repeat itself again.. like 4th will be red, 5th will be yellow, 6th will be Green and so on.

If the user enters 12. It will go like : 1 (of red color), 2 (of Yellow color), 3 (of Green color), 4 (red color), 5 (yellow color)...so on..till 12.

I can differentiate between integers on basis of EVen and Odd but in this case we have 3 different options : Red, Yellow and Green.

Comment: Look at the [Remainder Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_(.25)) - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lhg3pL56/1/

Comment: The colours can be done easily in CSS using the [nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can generate the numbers in a loop easily. As far as identifying the pattern goes, you could simply do this check (pseudo code):

```
  num are values generated from 1 to whatever you want to be.

 (num - 1) % 3 = 0  --> Color should be red
 (num + 1) % 3 = 0  --> Color should be yellow
   num % 3 = 0      --> Color should be green
```

Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_(.25))

```js
var num = 12;
var list = [],
  colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  list.push('<span class="' + colors[i % colors.length] + '">' + (i + 1) + '</span>')
}

var html = list.join('');
//add it to the dom to view
$('body').append(html);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
        $limit = 10;

        $color =  array('red','yellow','green');

        for($i=0;$i<=$limit;$i++)
             {
              echo "<span style='color:".$color[$i%3]."'>$i</span>";

             }

   ?>
```